# ChildControl of a childcontrol is null when calling from Main control

Tags: asp.net, controls

I built a webusercontrol  in asp.net which contains a databound dropdown. 
When I directly put this control into a webform it runs well. 
But if I try to add this control as childcontrol to another control at runtime

```
Childcontrol childcontrol = new Childcontrol ();
maincontrol.controls.add(childcontrol)
```

, the dropdown of the childcontrol is not instatiated (is null) so that I run in an exception by trying to bind the data to the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a user control (you have an ascx file?) then you need to use LoadControl so that ASP.NET instantiates the objects.